# If $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$, then so is $U+W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$. Define $$U+W=\{u+w:u\in U, w\in W\}.$$ Show that $U+W$ is a subspace of $V$.

I am new to the subject and I could use some guidance to start. I understand that $U$ and $W$ are subspaces and what a subspace is, and also that since $U$ and $W$ are both subspaces of $V$, $U+V$ will be a subspace.

Comment: Well, that's what you need to prove.  Is the zero vector in $U+V$?  If $\vec a, \vec b$ are both in $U+V$, can we conclude that $\vec a+\vec b$ is?  Can we conclude that $\lambda \vec a$ is, where $\lambda$ is a scalar?

Comment: Please, use MathJax

Answer (score 3):

I will help you a bit, first remember the definition of subspace:

> Let $\textsf{V}$ a vector space over a field $F$ and $\textsf{W}$ a
>   subset of $\textsf{V}$. We say that $\textsf{W}$ is a vector
>   *subspace* of $\textsf{V}$ if the following three conditions are satisfied:
>
> - $\textsf{W}\neq \varnothing$ or equivalently, that the zero vector is in $\textsf{W}$.
> - Whenever $x$ and $y$ are in $\textsf{W}$, their sum $x+y$ is also in $\textsf{W}$.
> - Whenever $x$ is in $\textsf{W}$, $ax$ is also in $\textsf{W}$ for all $a\in F$.

Now, we are ready to prove that $\textsf{U}+\textsf{W}=\{u+w:\, u\in\textsf{U} \textrm{ and } w\in \textsf{W}\}$ is a vector subspace as long as $\textsf{U}$ and $\textsf{W}$ are.

First, we may to check that $0_\textsf{V}\in \textsf{U}+\textsf{W}$. But since $\textsf{U}$ and $\textsf{W}$ are subspaces of $\textsf{V}$, $0_\textsf{V}$ is in both, then
$$0_\textsf{V}=0_\textsf{V}+0_\textsf{V}\in \textsf{U}+\textsf{W}$$
Now, let's take vectors $x$ and $y$ in $\textsf{U}+\textsf{W}$. Then $x=u_1+w_1$ and $y=u_2+w_2$ for some $u_1,u_2 \in \textsf{U}$ and $w_1,w_2\in \textsf{W}$. So
$$x+y=(u_1+w_1)+(u_2+w_2)=(u_1+u_2)+(w_1+w_2)$$
and since $ u_1 + u_2 \in \textsf{U} $ because $\textsf{U}$ is a subspace, and also $ w_1 + w_2 \in \textsf{W} $, we can say that $x+y\in \textsf{U}+\textsf{W}$ (because it is the sum of one element in $\textsf{U}$ and one in $\textsf{W}$).

Finally, let $x\in \textsf{U}+\textsf{W}$ and $a$ an arbitrary scalar (in $F$). Then $x=u+w$ for some $u\in \textsf U$ and $w\in \textsf W$ and then
$$ax=a(u+w)=au+aw\in \textsf{U}+\textsf{W}$$
since $au$ is an element of $\textsf{U}$ (for being a subspace) and $aw\in \textsf{W}$ for the same reason. Therefore $\textsf{U}+\textsf{W}$ fulfills the three conditions, and then we can say that it is a vector subspace of $\textsf{V}$.

*Additional data*: $\textsf{U}+\textsf{W}$ is the smallest subspace that contains both $\textsf{U}$ and $\textsf{W}$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that $U+W$ is non empty  and is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Note that $$(u_1+w_1)+(u_2+w_2) = (u_1+u_2)+(w_1+w_2) \in U+W$$

Also $$\lambda (u+w)= \lambda u +\lambda w \in U+W$$

Also $$0=0+0 \in U+W$$

Other properties are inherited from $V$

Answer (score 0):

(1) clearly non-empty

(2) Let $a,b \in U+W$ that means $a=u_1+w_2$ and $b=u_2+w_22$ Then $a+b=(u_1+u_2)+(w_1+w_2)$  since they are subspaces, $u_1+u_2$ is in U and $w_1+w_2$ is in W, and so $a+b$ is in in $U+W$

(3) a similar argument to (2) shows that the set is closed under scalar multiplication.